# Localization of custom keycloak login theme

Tags: keycloak

I am implementing a custom login page for keycloak (version 2.5), by following [this](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-developer-guide/content/topics/themes.html) guide. I added my own custom styling, now I am trying to add the Dutch locale. Currently no Dutch locale is provided, so I provided following properties files:

- `themes/mytheme/login/messages/messages_en.properties`
- `themes/mytheme/account/messages/messages_en.properties`
- `themes/mytheme/email/messages/messages_en.properties`

with the `locale_nl=Nederlands` property. After that I added the `messages_nl.properties` files with the translation strings.

Next I added the `locales=en,nl,de` property to following files:

- `themes/mytheme/login/messages/theme.properties`
- `themes/mytheme/account/messages/theme.properties`
- `themes/mytheme/email/messages/theme.properties`

There is only one thing left to do: add the Dutch locale in the admin console. But I can't select the `NL` locale after I enabled internationalization. I can only select the English and German locale, my just created Dutch locale is not available:

[image]

According to [Multilingual support and adding custom Locales in Keycloak](http://metalop.com/2015/06/11/multilingual-support-and-adding-custom-locales-in-keycloak-1-2-0/), I should be able to add my own locale by just typing the locale and hitting 'enter', but that does not do anything.

I am missing a step here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After reading the [code](https://github.com/stianst/keycloak/blob/b94f207c5c9e08d13c9fd743e407b53c91da3e7a/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin/resources/js/controllers/realm.js#L353), I understood only adding the files is not enough. You need to enable your theme not only for the `login` theme, but also for the `account` and `email` themes:

[image]

As I only changed the `login` theme to my own 'custom-theme', the Dutch locale did not show up.

Comment: I did all these but not helped me. I still did not see my new added language on admin window