# Unable to add custom pt-PT locale in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I'm using the latest release of Keycloak (v17.0.0).

I have created a new theme under /keycloak/themes directory as per specification. Within this directory I have created a theme.properties file and a messages directory that contains the new locale file "messages_pt_PT.properties". I did this for account, login, admin and email themes.

Directory structure:

[image]

When I try to specify the locale in Keycloak, once I click save it does not apply the locale.

**Screen before save:**

[image]

**Screen after clicking save:**

[image]

The theme pt-PT is not recognized in the "Supported Locales" field. What am I missing here?

Comment: I suggest you to download keycloak sources and add break point to corresponding locale management endpoint to trace down locales update. AFAIK there we some issues with Admin Console locale update implementation (I may be wrong), so you can also check update request flow with browser web developer window, or to trigger this request directly via Admin REST API

Comment: If anyone else runs into this issue, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855394/localization-of-custom-keycloak-login-theme All 4 them dropdowns must be in a theme that supports the desired location, in this post would be pt-PT.